# My Hero Academia fan fiction where Izuku Midoriya destroys the Pointer Robots in the Practical Entrance Exam

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-hero-academia

I remember that Izuku Midoriya destroys the Pointer Robots in the Practical Entrance Exam by making them fire on each other and the Zero Pointer, for basically the same reason as depicted in the original story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the sparseness of the question and details, I actually believe I read this a few weeks ago. I've read many BNHA fanfictions and hadn't actually seen this strategy before, which is why it stuck out to me when I read it.

### The Fanfic Is:

[Live a Hero](https://archiveofourown.org/works/14082885) by [BeyondTheClouds777](https://archiveofourown.org/users/BeyondTheClouds777/pseuds/BeyondTheClouds777)

**Here are some excerpts from Chapter 11:**

> A robot spins around the corner, and Izuku skids to a halt. The robot raises what Izuku assumes is its mechanical eye and looks at him. The red dilates.
>
> “Target locked,” chirps its robotic voice. The red light glows brighter, and Izuku barely has time to leap into the air before the blast is fired. It hits the asphalt where he’d been moments before, leaving a black crater in the street.
>
> Izuku rolls on his shoulder and bounces to his feet, facing the robot. It stares at him like it wasn’t quite expecting him to dodge; and then, with another bright light, it fires again.
>
> Izuku dodges this time, and the blast hits the cement harmlessly. Deciding that this is going nowhere and that he really needs a strategy, Izuku dives out of the way of another attack and hits the ground running.
>
> A whirring, clicking sound behind him says he’s being followed, but he keeps going, listening for the tell-tale fire-up of the robot’s canon. He has an idea, but for it to work, he needs—
>
> A second robot turns the corner in front of him, and it takes less than a second for it to lock on Izuku.
>
> “Target locked,” the second robot says, firing up a blast; behind him, Izuku hears the sound, and he waits until the very last second to make his move.
>
> He hears the blast behind him, the blast in front of him, and he leaps into the air. The robots’ respective blasts slam into each other, and they produce a couple sad whirring sounds before crashing to the ground in sad, smoldering heaps. Izuku rolls and gets his feet underneath him again shortly thereafter, gaze set forward.

---

> It’s actually going better than Izuku ever thought it would.
>
> Being pursued constantly by robots sure gives him a run for his money, and his throat is burning with the force of his gasps, but he won’t stop now. He hasn’t been keeping track of how many robots he’s beaten thus far, but he can’t shake off Aizawa’s words, that “all or nothing.”
>
> If he doesn’t come in first, if he doesn’t make it into Class A, he can’t go to U.A. Without Aizawa there should his Quirk go haywire, there’s no telling what he can do.
>
> So his path is obvious: take out as many robots as possible, then hope that somehow it’s enough.
>
> He keeps on with it, tricking robots into shooting each other. All he can say is, he’s glad he was able to start eating a bit healthier leading up to this; he isn’t sure his stamina would be able to hold out, otherwise.

---

> And then, up ahead, Izuku hears something. A small cry of pain, barely there, but still, he heard it.
>
> He turns, and the dust up ahead clears just enough for him to see Uraraka, pinned by a chunk of asphalt. Her face is contorted in pain, and she’s trying to reach behind her to touch the chunk of building, but she can’t reach around that far, and it seems trying brings more pain. Maybe her shoulder is dislocated.
>
> The Zero-Pointer continues down the street, straight toward her. It isn’t dangerously close yet, but it’s getting there. Slowly but steadily, it’s getting there. Izuku grits his teeth behind his lips, mind whirring. And then he turns and looks at the complacent robots.

---

> “Make me float!” Midoriya shouts, sprinting towards her, and for someone that’s yelling, his voice is surprisingly steady and calm. “Do that thing you were doing with the rocks! Send me up!” ...........
>
> “When I give you the signal, let me go!” Midoriya says down to her, calm despite the volume of his voice. “But only when I say so!” ............
>
> The robots fire their blasts, Midoriya’s voice rings “Now!” over the roaring in Ochako’s ears, and she taps her fingertips together and squeezes her eyes shut, not daring to look. She hears the crack, snap, and crunch of metal; then a wheezing, whirring sound, like clicking gears working against each other.....
>
> The Zero-Pointer, its glowing red eyes dark and lifeless, with a crater-like dent in the chestplate, is toppling down.

Comment: It was this one.